# How to disable multiselection on fabric.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm currently working on a canvas built with fabric.js.

I have three objects on a canvas:

1. First, that **cannot** be selected/resized/replaced
2. Second ,that behave the same as the first one
3. And a third one, which **can** be replaced/selected etc.

My problem is that when I multiselect them (by using my mouse),
they all became capable of resizing/replacing etc.

My question is:
How can I disable grouping them together, so that the first two objects cannot be select?

I have already tried `canvas.selection = false` - but this option disables the whole canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I follow your question but each object has a `selectable` property.
Perhaps that will help?

> **selectable** :*Boolean*
> When set to `false`, an object can not be selected
> for modification (using either point-click-based or group-based
> selection). But events still fire on it.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#selectable

Comment: Thank you @spring! It turns out, I was adding this option on a wrong configuration for the first two objects, what a shame. 
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

To disable the ability to click and drag in order to select multiple objects you can simply add a key:value pair in the options of the fabric.Canvas initialization...

`let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("some_id_attribute_value",{selection: false});`

The specific key value is selection:false and "some_id_attribute_value" is whatever you specified as the id of the canvas element(basic canvas init step).
I was also having this problem, hope this helps!